# How to show the right percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/252jxsjq/1/

how can I show 65 instead of 64.72343432...?

Finally,how can I make the number of clicks equal for all the user?
For example, now if i click 60 times on a button, if I change the pc the times displayed are 0.

jQuery:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;

$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );

 });

var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
});
```

Comment: Math.round(64.72343432) = 65

Comment: The only way to make that number persist across all users on all computers is to store the count on a server. Then you'll server those counts to each user and then each user will update the server value on every click.

Comment: Mike, could you teach me how to do that?

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi This isn't a school, do your own research. Look for tutorials on AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) Function of JavaScript.

```
$('.redanswer').click(function(){
 localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
 $( '.bpercent' ).html( Math.round( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) ) + "%" );
 $( '.rpercent' ).html( Math.round( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) ) + "%" );
});
```

Local storage saves state or variable to client machine (or say browser). 
As Mike said, If you want to save value for all devices, than You will need some server side Implementations which can manage clicks counter for all users all around the world.

Comment: `localStorage` is specific to the exact url, browser and machine. `local.example.com` and `example.com` have different `localStorage` objects.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i fix my first problem?

Comment: Use Math.floor instead, as Math.round will round the fractions higher than .5 to next bigger number

Comment: The reason why you don't get the correct values beyond 100% is because you are calculating the percentage => counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) which would never be more than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to make sure that when you're doing `counter1+counter` that you're adding integers and not concatenating strings.  `parseInt()` will help with that.

Also, as others have mentioned, `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` can help with that.

Something like this would work:

```
counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;



$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     sum = (parseInt(counter1) + parseInt(counter));
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( Math.floor(counter1 * 100 / sum) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( Math.floor(counter * 100 / sum) + "%" );

});

counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     sum = (parseInt(counter1) + parseInt(counter));
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( Math.floor(counter * 100 / sum) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( Math.floor(counter1 * 100 / sum) + "%" );
});
```

You can see it in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/252jxsjq/4/

As for permanent storage across different machines, look into some server side languages and storing information for different users.

Hope that helps!