# How can I get the right percentage on the first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/252jxsjq/1/

On the first click on a button it shows a wrong number. If you continue to click on the same button it continues to show the wrong number. But if you click the other button it shows the right percentage.What could the issue be ?

jQuery:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;

$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );

 });

var counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( counter * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( counter1 * 100 / (counter1+counter) + "%" );
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069044/how-to-show-the-right-percentage-after-a-jquery-code

Comment: @stark while indeed it´s the same question, the error is another

Comment: @DinoMyte the problem isn't that its showing 100%, the problem is that its not showing the correct percentage.  Thats happening where he's adding the counters, hes actually concatenating strings, not adding integers.

Comment: @Adam, I have to take it back. Didn't realize that until juvian's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem('rans')` returns a string, so you actually need to cast it to a number:

```
var counter = Number(localStorage.getItem('rans')) || 0;
var counter1 = Number(localStorage.getItem('bans')) || 0;
```

Comment: Not necessary, since the var type is generic, javascript converts it from string to number during any mathematical operations automatically.

Comment: @DinoMyte that is true for `counter * 100`, but not for `counter1+counter`

Comment: Oops. Didn't consider that part. +1

Comment: Indeed @juvian has something, the counters need to be converted to integers so they can be added instead of concatenated as strings.  Thats the reason the numbers are looking funny.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to make sure that when you're doing `counter1+counter` that you're adding integers and not concatenating strings.  `parseInt()` will help with that.

Also, as others have mentioned, `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()` can help with that.

Something like this would work:

```
counter = localStorage.getItem('rans') || 0;



$('.redanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('rans', ++counter);
     sum = (parseInt(counter1) + parseInt(counter));
     $( '.bpercent' ).html( Math.floor(counter1 * 100 / sum) + "%" );
     $( '.rpercent' ).html( Math.floor(counter * 100 / sum) + "%" );

});

counter1 = localStorage.getItem('bans') || 0;

$('.blueanswer').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('bans', ++counter1);
     sum = (parseInt(counter1) + parseInt(counter));
     $( '.rpercent' ).text( Math.floor(counter * 100 / sum) + "%" );
     $( '.bpercent' ).text( Math.floor(counter1 * 100 / sum) + "%" );
});
```

You can see it in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/252jxsjq/4/

As for permanent storage across different machines, look into some server side languages and storing information for different users.

Hope that helps!